# rendering pressure on a simple scene in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, move, lag, profiler

I have a pretty simple game just like bridge race(4 character collect some collectable from ground and put in on route). but when my character and AI's move in scene I see FPS drop and game running in 50 or 40 or sometimes 30 frames in Lg g4.
for my camera test I seprate the camera from character and say periodically move to right and left and see the lag again.

```
 if (x == -1)
     transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 2.7f;
 else
     transform.position -= Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 2.7f;
```

even with 40k poly scene I see rendering fill about 16 ms in each frame and this instruction eat up CPU.
EarlyUpdate.presentBeforeUpdate and PostLateUpdate.FinishFRameREndering are two part in profiler that get half of my CPU power. why lots of rendering pressure is on my CPU for just showing simple scene?
I see this profiler after build and run when show GPU diagram in profiler and some frame drop accured because of this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txjCP.png)
and this is another picture without showing gpu data. and frame rate is just like normal build.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW4ey.png)